# Pandas: select DataFrame matches and does not match condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two DFs as follows:

```
ID | A | B
1    0   1
2    1   2
3    2   2

Type | Name
1    |  ...
2    |  ...
1    |  ...
```

I want two DataFrame from the first one. The first one only has the rows where in the SECOND DF has `Type == 1`, and the other contains rows where in the second DF, `Type != 1`. This is my sample desired result:

```
First DF:
ID | A | B
1    0   1
3    2   2

Second DF:
ID | A | B
2    1   2
```

Let's call the first one `df` and the second one `df_other`. I tried this but it gave me the error

```
idx = df_other["Type"] == 1
df1 = df[~df.index.isin(idx)]
df2 = df[df.index.isin(idx)]
```

I also tried `loc[idx]` and `.iloc[idx, :]`, but they also gave wrong result. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you call the 'first one' `df` how does `df_other` have a column `A`? And why are you checking `A == 0` if you want to know where `Type == 1`?

Comment: Edited my answer. Sorry when trying to think an easy explanation I forgot to change it back.

Comment: Just remove `df.index.isin` from both lines? If `df` and `df_other` have corresponding rows

Comment: It throws me an error `IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).` `df` and `df_other` have the same number of rows, but different columns,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets call your dataframes `df1` and `df2`. I am assuming both have the same length.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

mask1 = np.select([df2['Type']==1, [True], default=False) #this creates a pandas series with True values were df2['Type'] is 1 and False everywhere else.

#### Your first dataframe would be
df1[mask1]
#### Your second dataframe is
df1[~mask1]

# if you want to save them as dataframes best use .copy() i.e.:
df_type1 = df1[mask1].copy()
df_typeNot1 = df1[~mask1].copy()
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's the same number of rows, and each dataframe is in the correct sort, merge/join them do the filtering:

```
data = {
        'ID':[1,2,3],
        'A':[0,1,2],
        'B':[1,2,2],
        }
dfa = pd.DataFrame(data)

data1 = {
        'Type':[1,2,1],
        'Name':['---','---','---']
        }
dfb = pd.DataFrame(data1)


df_merged = pd.concat([dfa, dfb], axis=1)
df1 = df_merged.loc[df_merged['Type']==1][['ID', 'A', 'B']].set_index('ID')
df2 = df_merged.loc[df_merged['Type']!=1][['ID', 'A', 'B']].set_index('ID')
print(df1)
print(df2)
```